# How to Detect If a Vim Register Only Contains Whitespace

Tags: vim, replace, whitespace

The vim help manual `:h character-classes` says that `\s` represents whitespace characters and `\S` represents non-whitespace characters.

Also the `n` flag tells you how many occurrences have been replaced.

I'm not sure how to actually incorporate this information into a solution, but I have a few ideas (not sure which ones, if any, are realizable).

1. Do a replacement on the value of the register with `\S`. If the replacement returns an error then you know that the register only contains whitespace.
2. Use `\S` and `n` with a replacement to see if the number of occurrences is greater than one, if so then you know that the register contains more than just whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually quite a bit simpler, using vimscript's comparison operators. Try this:

```
getreg('<reg>') !~ '\S'
```

(Obviously, you'll need to replace `<reg>` with whichever register you are using, for example `"a`, or `""`)

This expression will return 1 if the given register only contains whitespace, and 0 if it contains any non-whitespace.

The reason this code works is because `!~` checks if a certain regular expression *does not match* the given string. If the given string *doesn't* match any non-whitespace, it must only contain whitespace.

You can read more about the vimscript comparison operators at [`:h expr4`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr4) (Granted, this is a weird and unintuitive spot to look for them)

---

**Edit**

If you'd like this to match *any* whitespace, including newlines, you can use the underscore variant of `\s`. In this case, `\_s`. From [`:h /\_s`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/_x), we can see that adding the underscore before the 's' will add the newline character to that class. However, we'll need to slightly modify the comparison, because we're now testing for equality, not inequality. We could just do

```
getreg('<reg>'), =~ '\_s*'
```

but this doesn't work because `=~` checks if the regex matches anywhere. Even if there is no whitespace in the register, this will always match because `*` works with 0 matches too. If there was an *end of register* atom (similar to end of line, `$`), then we could do

```
getreg('<reg>'), =~ '^\_s*$'
```

but I'm not aware of any *beginning/end of register* atoms. So this approach is out. Instead, we'll just use matchstr, which returns the portion of the string that the pattern matches. Then we'll just compare that with the original register. I came up with this:

```
matchstr(@", '\_s*') == @"
```

(Also, note that I'm using `@"` instead of `getreg` here. As far as I'm aware, they are equivalent.)

Comment: Cool so it works with just spaces and tabs, but apparently vim doesn't consider newlines as whitespace. When I copy an empty line using `yy` and the register holds `^J` the `getreg()` command you showed me returns 0. Any ideas?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Except in the case of generic scripting (when we don't know the register name), do you see/know any advantage in using `getreg('a')` instead of `@a`?

Comment: @LucHermitte I am not aware of any differences between the to. Except that `@a` is writeable, so `let @a=foo` works but `let getreg('a')=foo` does not.